# use two time capsules together

Tags: network, wifi, airport, time-capsule

I want to use the newer time capsule as my wifi.  I need the second time capsule because I don't have enough wired ports. 
How can I connect the two of them?  I don't need the wifi on the second one.  Which one do I plug into the cable modem and how do I physically connect the second one as in do I plug it into the first one that has the wan cable plugged into it?  How do I configure them both? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I do this by using AirPort utility to turn off WiFi on the second Time Capsule. Configure it for:

- turn off the network which places it in bridge mode
- allow setup over WAN if you want to plug the WAN port of the second AirPort into one LAN port of the Time Capsule that runs as a router.

Leave all other settings default (so wipe restore the settings) and then give it a name and make the changes above.

So ethernet goes from the cable modem to the first TC WAN port. Then ethernet goes from the LAN port of first TC to the WAN or LAN port on the second TC.

[image]

[image]